# UnsupportedError thrown when setting localizationsDelegates

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to implement internationalization for my Flutter app but it won't let me use my preferred language (Indonesian).

[From the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html), it told me to add `localizationsDelegates` to my `MaterialApp`. Since I am using GetX, the `MaterialApp` here are wrapped inside the `GetMaterialApp`.

But when I did that, it throws me an error:

```bash
Exception has occurred.
UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map)
```

I tried to remove the `localizationsDelegates`, it throws me yet another error:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (No MaterialLocalizations found.
TabBar widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.
To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
  TabBar
```

*But when I hard code the `locale` property of my `GetMaterialApp` to `Locale('en', 'US')` and commented the `localizationsDelegates`, it works.*

Do you guys know why and how to fix this?

Anyways, here is how my `main.dart` (and some related files) look like.

`main.dart`

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Get.putAsync(() => EnvService().init());
  await Get.putAsync(() => IntlService().init());

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
      getPages: AppPages.routes,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      theme: MyAppTheme.light,
      darkTheme: MyAppTheme.dark,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // translations: AppTranslations(),
      locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('id', 'ID'),
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('id', 'ID'),
      ],
      //
      //
      // UNCOMMENT THIS LINE, YOUR PHONE WILL EXPLODE!
      // localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
    );
  }
}
```

`env_service.dart`

```dart
class EnvService extends GetxService {
  static EnvService get instance => Get.find();

  Future<EnvService> init() async {
    await dotenv.load();
    return this;
  }

  Locale get defaultLocale {
    final locale = dotenv.get('DEFAULT_LOCALE', fallback: 'id');
    
    if (locale != 'id') {
      return const Locale('en', 'US');
    }
    
    return Locale(locale, locale.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

`intl_service.dart`

```dart
class IntlService extends GetxService {
  static IntlService get instance => Get.find();

  Locale get _locale {
    return Get.locale ?? EnvService.instance.defaultLocale;
  }

  Future<IntlService> init() async {
    await initializeDateFormatting(_locale.countryCode);
    return this;
  }

  String formatCurrency(double number) {
    final formatter = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(decimalDigits: 0);
    return formatter.format(number);
  }

  String formatDate(DateTime? dateTime, [String? format]) {
    if (dateTime == null) {
      return '';
    }
    return DateFormat(format).format(dateTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem in the meantime?

Comment: no, not yet.. i dropped the localization feature for now

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you remove initializeDateFormatting(). And be aware that *Hot Reload* might not work if you make this change.

This works because `initializeDateFormatting()` calls `initializeDatePatterns()` with a const Map setting `dateTimePatterns` which is immutable after that. But `GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate` calls `initializeDateFormattingCustom()` which tries to write its map into `dateTimePatterns` at the end. That results in an "Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map". So if we do not call `initializeDateFormatting()`, this error does not happen because dateTimePatterns is not immutable when `initializeDateFormattingCustom()` is called. But the date formatting is initialized anyway because that is what `initializeDateFormattingCustom()` does with the formatting from `GlobalMaterialLocalizations`.

**This depends on intl ^0.17.0.**

Answer (score 0):

try add this in `GetMaterialApp`:

```
 localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
```

Comment: it's the same, I also tried that before

Comment: it is the same for me

Comment: This cannot work because you add here GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

GetX has its own way of localization

```
GetMaterialApp(
    title: 'My App',
    translations: AppTranslations(),
    locale: read('lang') == "" ? Get.deviceLocale : Locale(read('lang')) ,    // set your specific langauge code or use device locale
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
),
```

```
class AppTranslations extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    'en': {
      "appTitle" : "My App",
      "home": "Home",
    },
    'np': {
      "appTitle" : "My App",
      "home": "होम",
    }
  };
}
```

To change into different locale

```
Get.updateLocale(Locale('np'));
```

Comment: This is for general localization. If I want to format dynamic data like currencies, or date time fetched from database to my locale, then I need a custom Intl Service.